# Storing XML in SQL 2005 XMLNS issue

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to store XML in SQL 2005.  I have a very simple table with an Id and a XML column.

When the XML contains the attribute xmlns my searching doesn't work.

This is my XML;

```
insert into XMLTest (ItemXML) values ( 
'<MessageType>
    <ItemId id="ABC" xmlns="ss" />
    <Subject>sub</Subject>
</MessageType>
')
```

And this is my Query;

```
select itemid, ItemXML.query('(/MessageType/ItemId)') from XMLTest order by ItemId desc
```

If I change the attribute xmlns to anything else my query works.

I don't think I know enough about XML to understand what SQL is doing with the namespace.  But it must be processing it and storing it differently maybe?  Anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a XML namespace on your XML node, you need to use that when querying - something like this - either directly in every single `.query()` or `.value()` function locally like this:

```
SELECT 
   itemid, 
   ItemXML.query('declare namespace x="ss";(/MessageType/x:ItemId)') 
FROM 
   XMLTest 
ORDER BY 
   ItemId DESC
```

(see here on [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187013%28SQL.90%29.aspx) for more details about this approach), or if you need to reference that XML namespace a lot, you can also define it as a scope:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('ss' as x)
SELECT 
   itemid, 
   ItemXML.query('(/MessageType/x:ItemId)') 
FROM 
   XMLTest 
ORDER BY 
   ItemId DESC
```

See the details about `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` on [MSDN SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx)

Comment: That is it perfectly, thank you.  

Also Your code example works like a dream.